# How to change Entity class Fileds in Room Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

In my project, I am storing Data into local database.For that I am using Room Library. As per the android documentation I've created One Entity class,One abstract Database class,One Dao interface.I have successfully stored and retrieved data.

But now I want to add one field in Entity(Model Class). After updating that class and while i am saving data in database, it is crashing. It shows some error in Dao_Impl class.Actually it is an auto generated class.How do I solve this error?

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any change in Data manipulation language (DML) like Table Structure you must provide a migration strategy

```
Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), MyDb.class, "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME")
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2).build();

static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE YOUR_TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN YOUR_NEW_COLUMN_NAME TEXT");
    }
};
```

Here 1 is your old database version and 2 is the current database version. Don't  forget to add field to your entity class.

Comment: Thanks!. Where should I add this Static Migration method ?

Comment: Any where you want. But it is good where you write Room.databaseBuilder....

Answer (score 0):

you need to write migration for your database. follow https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions